# Does the upper bound of lower sums and the lower bound of higher sums depends on the type of intervals (open, closed or semi-open)?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have consulted many books and notes on internet on the Riemann integral but in none of them have I found whether the upper bound of lower sums and the lower bound of higher sums depends on the type of intervals (open, closed or semi-open) choose to partition the integration interval $ [a,b] $.In particular let:

$$ s(f,\left\{I_k\right\}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \inf_{x\in I_k} f(x) m(I_k)$$

the lower sums and:

$$ S(f,\left\{J_l\right\}) = \sum_{l=1}^m \sup_{x\in J_l} f(x) m(J_l)$$

the upper sums. Generally these values depend on whether you choose each individual $I_k$ ($1\leq k \leq n$) and $J_l$ ($1\leq l \leq m)$ open, closed , open right or open left.

Intuitively upper bound of lower sums and the lower bound of higher sums do not depends on the type of intervals. If so, what is the proof? And if not, can you explain to me why? is the demonstration based on tagged partitions?

Comment: Well you cannot choose open, clearly. Next, a half open interval is a subset of the closed interval, so that could get you somewhere.

Comment: A priori there is no reason to use only one kind of interval to determine the upper bound of lower sums and the upper bound of lower sums. Some books use closed intervals, some open intervals, and still others half-open intervals
Therefore it would be necessary to prove that the two extremes do not depend on the intervals used

Comment: Well, hopefully we agree that the intervals need to cover $[a,b]$. If you used anything but closed intervals, you would consequently need more than two types of intervals to cover $[a,b]$.

Comment: it is not necessary to "cover" the integration interval [a,b] (it is not the purpose of the definition of integral). So much so that there are texts of mathematical analysis that use open intervals (analisi 1 Pagani-Salsa) and intervals open to the right (analisi 1 Enrico Giusti).

Comment: If you do not cover $[a,b]$, say by restricting yourself to open intervals, then you admit that the end points $\{a,b\}$ are superfluous. There is no, rigorous, a priori reason to justify this, unless you have already shown that they are via the usual approach.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Zhang
  for answering me

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4242877/72031

Comment: Thanks Paramanand Singh !