New Definitions of Upper & Lower Integrals
Let $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. To be simple, only upper Darboux sum and integral will be discussed.
The upper Darboux sum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ based on a partition $P = \{z_0,z_1,\dots,z_n\}$, where $z_0=a<z_1<\dotsb<z_n=b$, is defined by
$$
U(f,P,[a,b]) = \sum_{i=1}^n{(z_i-z_{i-1})\sup_{[z_{i-1},z_i]}f}.
$$
Then, the upper Riemann integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is defined by
$$
U(f,[a,b]) = \inf\{U(f,P,[a,b])\colon \text{$P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$}\}.
$$
Now, we offer a new definition for upper Darboux sum, taking supremum on open partitioned intervals instead of the closed one:
$$
U^*(f,P,[a,b]) = \sum_{i=1}^n{(z_i-z_{i-1})\sup_{(z_{i-1},z_i)}f},
$$
and
$$
U^*(f,[a,b]) = \inf\{U^*(f,P,[a,b])\colon \text{$P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$}\}.
$$
with lower ones redefined in the same way. My questions are:

Will the upper integral change or not?

If the upper integral changes for some functions, will the Riemann integrability of them change or not?


My Progress
We distinguish the original and new definitions by $L,U$ and $L^*, U^*$, respectively.
Firstly, as $f$ is bounded, "new" lower and upper Darboux sums can be defined for all partition $P$. It is trivial that
$$
L^*(f,P,[a,b])\leq U^*(f,P,[a,b])
$$
for all partition $P$,
so the set $\{U^*(f,P,[a,b])\colon \text{$P$ is a partition}\}$ is bounded below and $U^*(f,[a,b])$ exists.
By the difference between original and new definitions, we have
$$
U^*(f,P,[a,b])\leq U(f,P,[a,b]);
$$
hence
$$
U^*(f,[a,b])\leq U(f,[a,b]).
$$
Still, if $P'$ is a refinement of $P$, then
$$
U^*(f,P',[a,b])\leq U^*(f,P,[a,b]).
$$
Suppose $U^*(f,P,[a,b])<U(f,P,[a,b])$. Set $2\epsilon = U(f,[a,b])-U^*(f,[a,b])>0$. For $\epsilon$, there exists a partition $\hat{P}$ s.t.
$$
U^*(f,[a,b])\leq U^*(f,\hat{P},[a,b])<U^*(f,[a,b])+\epsilon<U(f,[a,b])\leq U(f,\hat{P},[a,b]).
$$
Now I'm stuck here. My purpose is to show that: when a refinement sequence of partitions based on $\hat{P}$ is applied, $U^*(f,\hat{P},[a,b])$ and $U(f,\hat{P},[a,b])$ can be arbitrarily small, which leads to a contradiction.

If ${P_n}$ is the partition sequence, with $P_1=\hat{P}$ and $P_n$ being a refinement of $P_{n-1}$ for each $n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} {U(f,P_n,[a,b])}=U(f,[a,b])$. It suffices to show that $U^(f,P_n,[a,b])$ converges to $U^(f,[a,b])$ and $U^*(f,P_n,[a,b])-U(f,P_n,[a,b])$ converges to $0$.

See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4253672/72031.

1. No, the definition does not change. For this, it suffices to show:

Claim. For any bounded function $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$, we have
$$ U(f, [a, b]) \leq U^*(f, P, [a, b]). $$

Proof. Let $M > 0$ be a bound of $f$, and let $P = \{a = z_0 < z_1 < \ldots < z_n = b\}$ be an arbitrary partition of $[a, b]$. Then, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist points $\{p_i\}_{i\in[1:n]}\subset [a, b]$ and $\{q_i\}_{i\in[1:n]}\subset [a, b]$ such that the following holds for all $i \in [1:n]$:
$$ z_{i-1} < p_i < q_i < z_i, \qquad
|p_i - z_{i-1}| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4Mn}, \qquad 
|z_i - q_i| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4Mn}. $$
Then, $Q = \{ z_i \}_{i\in[0:n]} \cup \{p_i\}_{i\in[1:n]} \cup \{q_i\}_{i\in[1:n]}$ is a partition of $[a, b]$. For simplicity, write
$$ A_i = [z_{i-1}, p_i], \qquad
J_i = [p_i, q_i], \qquad 
B_i = [q_i, z_i]. $$
Then $
\begin{align*}
U(f, Q, [a, b])
&= \sum_{i\in[1:n]} \left( |A_i| \sup_{A_i}f + |B_i| \sup_{B_i}f + |J_i| \sup_{J_i}f \right) \\
&\leq \sum_{i\in[1:n]} \left( |A_i| M + |B_i| M + |J_i| \sup_{(z_{i-1}, z_i)}f \right) \\
&\leq \sum_{i\in[1:n]} \left( 2(|A_i| + |B_i|) M + |z_i - z_{i-1}| \sup_{(z_{i-1}, z_i)}f \right) \\
&\leq \sum_{i\in[1:n]} \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{n} + |z_i - z_{i-1}| \sup_{(z_{i-1}, z_i)}f \right) \\
&= \varepsilon + U^*(f, P, [a, b]).
\end{align*}
Hence, $ U(f, [a, b]) \leq \varepsilon + U^*(f, P, [a, b])$ holds. Since both $U(f, [a, b])$ and $U^*(f, P, [a, b])$ are independent of $\varepsilon$, letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ shows the desired inequality.

Thanks for your answer, and I believe you remove the influence of boundary point to supremums on each partition interval by limiting them to smaller intervals.

Nice argument. +1 I handled the same problem in a slightly different manner at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4253672/72031
